# Setting a LIMIT by a parameter other than number of rows

Tags: mysql

I have an application that searches and shows user recommendations of different Institutions.

Each Institution can have any number of recommendations.

The results are presented per institute like so:

- Inst A has 6 recommendations
- inst B has 4 recommendations
- and so on...

I want to draw only ten **Institutions** at a time.

The problem is that my query refers to **recommendations**, and not to institutions, and therefore I end up getting 10 recommendations instead of 10 institutions.

Is there a way to tell MySQL that the limit refers to DISTINCT institutions, while still pulling in effect DUPLICATE institutions (i.e a number of recommendations on the same institute)?

The simpified versions of the actual query:

```
SELECT * FROM institutions
LEFT JOIN recommendations
  ON institutions.InstitutionID = recommendations.InstitutionID
WHERE [SOMETHING]
LIMIT 10
```

a different way to present the question: Is it possible to make the LIMIT clause refer to the original SELECT without the JOIN?

Comment: What is exact the query you're using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put the limit on institutions, then join from that:

```
SELECT * FROM (
    select *
    from institutions
    WHERE [SOMETHING about institutions]
    LIMIT 10) x
LEFT JOIN recommendations ON x.InstitutionID =  recommendations.InstitutionID
    AND [SOMETHING about recommendations]
```

For pagination in mysql, use this:

```
...
LIMIT 50, 10
```

This example gets the 6th page - starting at row 51 and getting 10 rows.
Note: offset counts from `0` not `1`.

The [syntax for limit](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/select.html) in mysql is `LIMIT offset, row_count`. Without offset, it's `LIMIT row_count` (I know... the row_count parameter moves!)

You can also use the alternate syntax:

```
...
LIMIT 10 OFFSET 50
```

I find this latter syntax far easier to read.

Comment: Thanks. The only problem is getting the total number of institutions for pagination purposes. I tried placing SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS on the sub query but got an error

Comment: Thanks, but that wasn't my question. I know how to use pagination. My concern is that while I only retrieve 10 rows, I need to know the Total number of rows in order to present the correct number of pages in the pagination (total / per_page). This is normally done with adding SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS after the SELECT keyword, and then retrieving the total with another query: SELECT FOUND_ROWS() as NUM_ROWS. However, in your solution It is not possible because the original table is already limited to 10 by the subquery and adding SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS to the subquery results in an error

Answer (score 1):

When you are joining make a sub query with the institution and put the limit there

```
SELECT * 
  FROM nsrecommendation
  JOIN (select * from nsserviceplace limit 10) as ten_service_places
 WHERE ten_service_places.NSServicePlaceID = nsrecommendation.NSServicePlaceID 
   AND [something];
```

Comment: shouldn't nsrecommendation have the limit 10 on it rather than nsserviceplace since he wants recommendation for each institution?

Comment: I think nsserviceplace is the institution and nsrecommendation is the recommendation.

Answer (score 0):

You could try some nested query to get the data you need if you only want to use mysql query as the way of retrieving the data. Can't tell much without the table structure.